# Unused Screen Space

Tags: lubuntu, display, screen, display-resolution

my name is Jorge and I use Lubuntu. The edges of my computer screen is not being used entirely even though my dock is taking up the entire bottom of the screen. I am somewhat know a bit of Lubuntu, so I might have done something wrong when trying to change a display setting. Please help me with this problem!
Edit: Every Window that I use is limited to only the space of the non-greyed out display. I can't expand it to take up all the screen. If there is any information I can give out to resolve this problem, I would gladly give it out. I heavily depend on my laptop for my everyday life so having this solved the quickest as possible would be great.
[image: greyed out edges]

*Look as my calendar and the Lubuntu icon takes up the screen dimensions correctly while all my windows and the wallpaper are limited to the smaller display.*

Comment: You didn't provide your release of Lubuntu, however I suspect your issue is the *theme* you have selected in Openbox Settings (ie. https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.11/openbox_settings.html in the manual).  I suspect you have something where the window borders aren't showing, either because you've selected an inappropriate theme for LXQt, or some other choice. I maybe wrong, but it's where I'd suggest you look first.

Comment: I have Lubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I think he could be referring to an effect of (what would be on my gnome-flashback desktop) the damn near invisible "separators"... If I inadvertently drag one across the panel it confines all of the windows to the smaller space. I don't know if lubuntu has those??? I know even less about themes... but I do know how to create that problem with separators... That is, if, that is what he is referring to... If it is, then "greyed out" is probably a bad description. It took me a while to figure out what he was talking about. I would say "unused panel space"... again, if, i am understanding.

Comment: I didn't read your screen (*earlier*), but on it I see LXDE modifications, don't forget they are for a different desktop to what you're using, ie. Lubuntu 18.04 LTS and earlier used LXDE, however 18.10 and later use LXQt, which whilst similar (many of the *devs* from LXDE are now on LXQt, many are from RazorQt and LXQt contains what was RazorQt source code too).  The `openbox` settings will remain the same, but LXDE & LXQt are not identical.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my own question. I figured out that they were "panels". All I had to do was simply remove them by clicking right click and the choosing the option "remove panel". Thank all of you for trying to help me. I honestly feel really embarrassed right now.

Comment: FYI:  I have panels on two borders on each of my two monitors; I do have 3 set to auto-hide (so they only appear when my mouse is over them, each is configured differently (side panels are really just quick-launch bars like Unity's dock, see https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html - but Well Done for working it out yourself anyway.